# WPF 4 DataGrid: Showing & Hiding Columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to implement column chooser functionality for a DataGrid and am running into problems if I try to define the content of the header for the column as something more than just a string.  Below is a very simplified example with all styles, view models, binding, etc all stripped out.

There are 3 columns:

The first column uses a string for the header.
The second column tries to set the header content to a Label with a ToolTip.
The third column ties to set the header content to a TextBlock with a ToolTip.

Clicking the Toggle Visibility button for Column A works fine.  The Toggle Visibility buttons for both Columns B and C cause an InvalidOperationException with the message "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridColumnChoosing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
        <TextBlock Margin="15, 0">Toggle Visibility:</TextBlock>
        <Button Click="ToggleA">Column A</Button>
        <Button Click="ToggleB">Column B</Button>
        <Button Click="ToggleC">Column C</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- Main Fuel Mileage Datagrid -->
    <DataGrid  x:Name="mySampleDataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                    GridLinesVisibility="All" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colA" Width="40*" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Column A">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colB" Width="40*" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <Label Content="Column B" ToolTip="A short explanation of Column B"/>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colC" Width="40*" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Column C" ToolTip="A short explanation of Column C " />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The simple click event handlers for the buttons that are toggling the visibility in this example are simply modifying the visibility of the columns.

```
    private void ToggleA(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        colA.Visibility = colA.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void ToggleB(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        colB.Visibility = colB.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void ToggleC(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        colC.Visibility = colC.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden : System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: My OCD says pleeeeaaasse switch the event handlers ToggleA and ToggleB, so they are in alphabetical order. *twitch*

Comment: LOL, I swapped them for you to prevent excess twitching.

Comment: While specific to a ComboBox; have you looked here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/496959/specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it-first

Comment: Interesting, but if it fits somehow, I am not finding how. The error happens with or without the tooltips on the textblock (or label) in the Header definition...and following their workaround of wrapping the tool tips with <ToolTip></ToolTip>, I'm not quite sure what I'd wrap around the content of my header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this issue once when I had a control defined in my Resources, and was trying to use it within multiple control's Content areas. That does not work because the control can only belong to one parent.

Instead, I needed to define a Template of some kind which contained the control I wanted, and set the Template of my object instead of the content directly.

Your comment on @Gimno's answer makes me think this is the case.

Try changing it so instead of setting a Label/TextBox in DataGrid.Header's content directly, set DataGrid.HeaderTemplate to a DataTemplate which contains the Label or TextBox.

**EDIT**

Here's some example code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colB" Width="40*" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="Column B" ToolTip="A short explanation of Column B"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Sounded logical, but it didn't work.  I swiped a sample of content control from MSDN. (oh well, code won't go in here)  I set the header to a content control that pointed at a style which output the string...still threw the error.

Comment: You need to set the actual Template, not the Content. The problem I had before is I was trying to set a `ContentControl.Content` and I needed to be setting `ContentControl.ContentTemplate`. I think you have the same issue... you should be setting `DataGrid.HeaderTemplate` instead of `DataGrid.Header`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Rachel, thankfully, that really didn't work how I expected it to.  I was expecting the Template property in the HeaderStyle definition to be the same thing as the HeaderTemplate and for the two definitions to duke it out for which was implemented.  Luckily, I was wrong, works like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easiest if you just use `DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle` instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn.Header`

As example for column c:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colC" Width="40*" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Column C"  ToolTip="A short explanation of Column C "/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: That would be easiest for a sample like this, but the DataGrid this sample was built for has about 20 columns which all share the same custom ContentTemplate (as do other DataGrids in the same application).  The use of DataGridTemplateColumn.Header allows me to have a ContentPresenter in my template and only define the template once.

Comment: Ok, that changes it. I would go for Rachels solution

Answer (score 0):

I liked the column chooser solution from CodePlex:
[DataGrid Behavior](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=UserDatagridBehavior)

I clean up the code and remove unnecessary code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace Behaviors
{
    public class WpfDataGridConfigurationBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
    {

        #region "public Properties"


        public bool DontPersistVisibleColumns { get; set; }
        public bool DontPersistColumnsOrder { get; set; }

        public string ContextMenuChoices { get; set; } = "Alphabetical Menu,Show All Columns";

        public string DataGridName { get; set; }

        #endregion "public Properties"

        #region "private Properties"

        private DataGrid dataGrid;

        private ContextMenu theContextMenu; // Context Menu for the field chooser.

        private string AllColumnsHeaders { get; set; }
        private string AllColumnDisplayIndexes { get; set; }

        private int nBaseItems = 5;
        private MenuItem mnuAlpha;
        private MenuItem mnuShowAll;

        #endregion "Private Properties"

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            dataGrid = this.AssociatedObject as DataGrid;
            if (DataGridName == null) DataGridName = dataGrid.Name;

            ContextMenu_BuildStaticMenu();

            dataGrid.Loaded += (sender, e) => { DataGrid_Loaded(); };
            dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns;

            dataGrid.ColumnReordered += (sender, e) => { DataGrid_ColumnReordered(sender); };

            dataGrid.ContextMenuOpening += (sender, e) => { DataGrid_ContextMenuOpening(e); };

            dataGrid.LoadingRow += (sender, e) => { e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString(); };

            dataGrid.RowHeaderWidth = 0;
            var ns = new Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader)) { BasedOn = dataGrid.RowHeaderStyle };
            ns.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
            ns.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, 11.0));
            ns.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(4, 0, 4, 0)));
            dataGrid.RowHeaderStyle = ns;
        }

        private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid_Loaded();
        }


        #region "DataGrid Events"


        private void DataGrid_ContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            var dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);

            if (dep == null)
                return;

            if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
            {
                // do something
            }

            if (dep is DataGridCell)
            {
                // navigate further up the tree
                while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
                    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);

                var row = dep as DataGridRow;

                dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row);
            }
        }

        private void DataGrid_ColumnReordered(object sender)
        {
            Settings_SaveDisplayIndexes(sender);

            ContextMenu_BuildMenu();
        }

        private void DataGrid_Loaded()
        {
            ContextMenu_BuildMenu(false);

            VisibleColumns_Initialize();
        }

        #endregion "DataGrid Events"

        #region "ContextMenu Methods and Events"

        private void ContextMenu_BuildStaticMenu()
        {
            theContextMenu = new ContextMenu { FontSize = 11, StaysOpen = true };

            mnuAlpha = new MenuItem
            {
                Header = ContextMenuChoices.Split(',')[0],
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                IsCheckable = true,
                StaysOpenOnClick = true
            };
            mnuAlpha.Click += (sender, e) => { ContextMenu_BuildMenu(); };

            mnuShowAll = new MenuItem
            {
                Header = ContextMenuChoices.Split(',')[1],
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                IsCheckable = true,
                StaysOpenOnClick = true
            };
            mnuShowAll.Checked += (sender, e) => { VisibleColumns = AllColumnsHeaders; };
            mnuShowAll.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (mnuShowAll.IsChecked == false) VisibleColumns_Initialize();
            };


            theContextMenu.Items.Add(mnuShowAll);
            theContextMenu.Items.Add(mnuAlpha);
        }

        private void ContextMenu_BuildMenu(bool pbRebuild = true)
        {
            for (int i = theContextMenu.Items.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
                if (((MenuItem)theContextMenu.Items[i]).FontWeight != FontWeights.Bold)
                    theContextMenu.Items.Remove(theContextMenu.Items[i]);

            nBaseItems = theContextMenu.Items.Count;

            // Attach the context menu to the DataGrid ColumnHeaders
            var headersPresenter = WpfDataGridConfigurationBehaviorFinder.FindChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(dataGrid);
            ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(headersPresenter, theContextMenu);

            if (VisibleColumns == null)
                throw (new SettingsPropertyNotFoundException("User's VisibleColumns setting not found."));

            // Get the current column ordering from user.config

            if (DisplayIndexes == null)
                throw (new SettingsPropertyNotFoundException("User's DisplayIndexes setting not found."));

            AllColumnDisplayIndexes = DisplayIndexes;
            string[] colIndexes = AllColumnDisplayIndexes.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var dataGridColumns = dataGrid.Columns.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayIndex);

            // Sort the columns in display index order so menu header order matchs display column order
            if (pbRebuild == false)
                // Initially the datagrid column order is such that display indexes are the same as the col indexes
                if (colIndexes.Length > 0)
                    dataGridColumns = dataGrid.Columns.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt16(colIndexes[x.DisplayIndex]));

            if (mnuAlpha.IsChecked)
                dataGridColumns = dataGrid.Columns.OrderBy(x => x.Header.ToString());

            AllColumnsHeaders = "";
            foreach (var col in dataGridColumns)
            {
                // All column name to a list of all column headers for later use.
                AllColumnsHeaders = $"{col.Header.ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ")};{AllColumnsHeaders}";

                // Add new menu item in display order.
                ContextMenu_AddNewMenuItem(col);
            }

            string sTemp = VisibleColumns;
            VisibleColumns = null;
            VisibleColumns = sTemp;

        }

        private void ContextMenu_AddNewMenuItem(DataGridColumn col)
        {
            var menuItem = new MenuItem { Header = col.Header.ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " "), StaysOpenOnClick = true };
            var saVisibleColumns = new List<string> { string.Empty };
            if (VisibleColumns != null)
            {
                saVisibleColumns = VisibleColumns.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }

            menuItem.IsChecked = (saVisibleColumns.Contains(menuItem.Header));
            menuItem.Click += (sender, e) => { ContextMenu_ColumnName_Click(sender); };

            theContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
        }

        private void ContextMenu_ColumnName_Click(object sender)
        {
            var mi = sender as MenuItem;

            // Get the column name that was clicked
            string colName = mi.Header.ToString();


            // Capture new visible columns list
            Settings_SaveVisibleColumns(mi, colName);
        }

        #endregion "ContextMenu Methods and Events"

        #region "Settings Methods"

        private void Settings_SaveVisibleColumns(MenuItem mi, string colName)
        {
            if (theContextMenu.Items.Count - nBaseItems < dataGrid.Columns.Count)
                return;

            // Put the visible column names into an array
            var saVisibleColumns = VisibleColumns.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            if (saVisibleColumns != null && saVisibleColumns.Count > 0 &&
                saVisibleColumns[saVisibleColumns.Count - 1].StartsWith("-"))
                saVisibleColumns.RemoveAt(saVisibleColumns.Count - 1);

            // If the menu item is unchecked (column is not visible)
            if (!mi.IsChecked)
                // Make the column visible by adding its name to the Visible Columns list
                saVisibleColumns.Add(colName);

            else
            // Hide the column by removing its name from the VisibleColumns list
            if (saVisibleColumns.Contains(colName) && saVisibleColumns.Count > 1)
                saVisibleColumns.Remove(colName);

            VisibleColumns = string.Join(";", saVisibleColumns) + ";";
        }

        private void Settings_SaveDisplayIndexes(object sender)
        {
            // Capture the new column order
            AllColumnDisplayIndexes = "";
            foreach (DataGridColumn col in ((DataGrid)sender).Columns)
            {
                AllColumnDisplayIndexes +=
                    (AllColumnDisplayIndexes.Length > 0 ? ";" : "") + col.DisplayIndex;
            }

            DisplayIndexes = AllColumnDisplayIndexes;
        }

        #endregion "Settings Methods"

        #region DisplayIndexes (DependencyProperty)

        public string DisplayIndexes
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayIndexesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayIndexesProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayIndexesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayIndexes", typeof(string), typeof(WpfDataGridConfigurationBehavior), new PropertyMetadata("", OnDisplayIndexesChanged));

        private static void OnDisplayIndexesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((WpfDataGridConfigurationBehavior)d).DisplayIndexesChanged(e);
        }

        public void DisplayIndexesChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Persist the new column order
            if (dataGrid != null && !DontPersistColumnsOrder)
                Settings_Save(DataGridName + "DisplayIndexes", AllColumnDisplayIndexes);
        }

        #endregion "DisplayIndexes (DependencyProperty)"

        #region VisibleColumns (DependencyProperty)

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating the names of columns 
        /// (as they appear in the column header) to be visible, seperated by a semicolon.
        /// 
        /// Columns whose names are not here will be hidden.
        /// </summary>

        public string VisibleColumns
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(VisibleColumnsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisibleColumnsProperty, value); }
        }

        private void VisibleColumns_Initialize()
        {
            // Get saved VisibleColumns from app.config
            // Initialize VisibleColumns
            VisibleColumns = string.IsNullOrEmpty(VisibleColumns.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ")) ? AllColumnsHeaders : VisibleColumns;
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("VisibleColumns", typeof(string), typeof(WpfDataGridConfigurationBehavior), new PropertyMetadata("", OnVisibleColumnsChanged));

        private static void OnVisibleColumnsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((WpfDataGridConfigurationBehavior)d).VisibleColumnsChanged(e);
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// Updates the display
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        public void VisibleColumnsChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (theContextMenu == null)
                return;

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                var showTheseColumns = e.NewValue.ToString().Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var saContextMenuVisibleItems = new List<string>();

                int iCol = 0;

                foreach (MenuItem menuItem in theContextMenu.Items)
                {
                    // Show/Hide the Context Menu item's checkmark.
                    if (menuItem.FontWeight == FontWeights.Bold) continue;

                    menuItem.IsChecked = showTheseColumns.Contains(menuItem.Header.ToString());
                    if (menuItem.IsChecked) saContextMenuVisibleItems.Add(menuItem.Header.ToString());

                    mnuShowAll.IsChecked = mnuShowAll.IsChecked && menuItem.IsChecked;

                    // Assign menu item's column's DisplayIndex in display order, (i.e. in menu item order), looking up each column by header name.)
                    if (mnuAlpha.IsChecked == false)
                        dataGrid.Columns.First(x => x.Header.ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ") == menuItem.Header.ToString()).DisplayIndex = iCol++;
                }

                // Show the columns
                foreach (var col in dataGrid.Columns)
                    col.Visibility =
                        showTheseColumns.Contains(col.Header.ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " "))
                        && (saContextMenuVisibleItems.Contains(col.Header.ToString().Replace("\n", " ")
                            .Replace("\r", " ")))
                            ? Visibility.Visible
                            : Visibility.Collapsed;

                // Persist the new visible columns list

                if (dataGrid != null && !DontPersistVisibleColumns)
                    Settings_Save(DataGridName + "VisibleColumns", VisibleColumns);

            }
        }

        #endregion "VisibleColumns"

        public static void Settings_Save(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
        {
            foreach (SettingsPropertyValue property in Settings.Default.PropertyValues)
            {
                if (propertyName == property.Name)
                {
                    property.PropertyValue = propertyValue;
                    Settings.Default.Save();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
     public static class WpfDataGridConfigurationBehaviorFinder
    {
        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm obj is valid. 
            if (depObj == null) return null;

            // success case
            if (depObj is T) return depObj as T;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                T obj = FindChild<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i));
                if (obj != null) return obj;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public interface IBreakVisualParenting
        {
            DependencyObject Parent { get; }
        }

        public static T LastVisualAncestorOfType<T>(this DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            T item = null;

            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent is T)
                    item = (T)parent;
                if (parent is IBreakVisualParenting)
                {
                    parent = ((IBreakVisualParenting)parent).Parent;
                }
                else
                    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            }

            return item;
        }

    }
}
```